# Reload only a <DIV> and php code with in that div

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have below code in a page called home.php.

```
<div class="Wrapper-notify" id="Wrapper-notify">
           <?php  echo rand(10,100); ?>
    </div>
```

How can I reload only this div and the php code on regular time interval. **(I'm using codeigniter framework)** please help

Comment: You cant do it how you imagine. You can either have a controller method that returns just that, eg `SnippetController->getWrapperNotify();`, and call that with ajax, or in this specific case, just do all your logic in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create a .php page, let's say test.php printing data like this :

```
<?php
    echo rand(10,100);
?>
```

An you can use this code to load data from your page, this one is pure javascript

```
function getValue()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    else
    AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (AJAX)
    {
        AJAX.open("GET", "test.php", false);
        AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        AJAX.send();
        return AJAX.responseText;                                         
    } 
    else
        return null;
}
window.onload=function()
{
    setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("Wrapper-notify").innerHTML = getValue();
    },1000);
};
```

However, if you are using jQuery you can the use .get method to load data from server

```
$(document).ready( function() 
{
    setInterval(function(){ changeDiv(); },1000);
});
function changeDiv()
{
    $.ajax({
         url: "test.php",
         success: function(result)
         {
            $("#Wrapper-notify").html(result);
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is evaluated on the server-side, so you will need to make a call to the server in order to re-evaluate the PHP expression. Considering that the only thing your PHP seems to be doing is generating a random number, and depending on what you're trying to accomplish overall, you might consider using Javascript to "refresh" the div, instead. You could do something like this:

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


function refreshDiv() {
    var divObj = document.getElementById("Wrapper-notify");
    var randNum = getRandomInt( 10 , 100 );
    divObj.innerHTML = String( randNum );
}

setInterval( "refreshDiv()" , 2000 );
```

The above Javascript will change the number inside the div every 2 seconds.

Comment: +1, pretty much exactly what I was going to say. It probably won't make a significant difference to performance but you could take the `getElementById` out of the function so that it isn't run multiple times unnecessarily. Also, you should just pass `refreshDiv` to `setInterval`, rather than the string. http://jsfiddle.net/zRjVh/

Comment: @TomFenech Quite right. I never knew you could pass anything other than a string as the first parameter to setInterval. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: thanks but actually my purpose is to learn how to reload a div and php code within it

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for this,

1. You define a function that will talk with your server to get data.

   **$('div #Wrapper-notify').load('http://yoursite.com #newContent');**
2. Set time interval using function and call that in a regular time period like below.

   **setInterval( function() {
          $('div #Wrapper-notify').load('http://yoursite.com #newContent');
       }, 6000); // every 6000 milliseconds**

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do it with AJAX. Do a `setInterval` in Javascript that executes a function every x seconds. That function should call your PHP file via AJAX and pass the response to your DIV. The PHP file should just contain

```
<?php  echo rand(10,100); ?>
```

This method is probably overkill for what you're probably aiming to achieve though.

Answer (score 0):

I only see one simple solution, ajax call to a php in a time interval and just push the response into a container:

This is an example using jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.get('/my/page', function(data) {
      $('#my_container').html(data);
    })
}, 3000);
```

Comment: There's a difference between Javascript and JQuery. You might mention this requirement in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need random number between 10 and 100 , no need for php ... you need just some javascript : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uk9RN/)

```
window.onload=function()
{
    setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("Wrapper-notify").innerHTML = parseInt((Math.random()*100)+10);
    },1000);
};
```

and if you're using some jQuery you can use this : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJ2D7/)

```
$(document).ready( function() 
    {
        setInterval(function(){$("#Wrapper-notify").html(parseInt((Math.random()*100)+10))},1000);
    });
```

Comment: thanks but my purpose is to learn how to reload a div and php code within it

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to create new action, that will output only rand number from 10 to 100. Lets call it for example get_rand_num_action:

   public function get_rand_num_action(){
       return mr_rand(10,100);
   }
2. In your view (where you have Wrapper-notify div), in the end of the  or in  tag  create new ajax request to your get_rand_num_action
3. Gather data from get_rand_num_action response and update your Wrapper-notify div using native JS or jQuery:

   function changeWrapperDiv(){
           $.ajax('/controller/get_rand_num_action', {
               success: function(response){
                   $("#Wrapper-notify").text(response);
               }
           });
       }

   ```
   // Change div every 5 seconds
   setInterval(5000, changeWrapperDiv)
   ```

Hope this will help you.